# Find mount points with 100% usage unix

Tags: unix, diskspace, mount-point

All,

I need to get the list of mount points that reached 100% of allocated disk space.

I did the following to get the mount point details in my server and its works fine by giving the details of all mount points.

> df -k

But when I need to list down the mount points reached 100% disk allocation, i am stuck.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?:

df -h | grep "100%" | awk '{ print $5 }'

Comment: got the following error`
df: illegal option -- h
usage : df [-F FStype] [-V] [-egiklnvsfb] [-t|-P] [-o specific_options]
           [special | directory ...]
`

Comment: `df -k | sort -n -k4` will give you a sorted list with highest % used mount-points at the bottom, which might also help.

Comment: You need to tell us what operating system you are using and post some sample `df -k` output.

Comment: All, I just achieved it by using following command: `df -P | grep "100%"` which is derived from @figurebelow 's answer. Thanks all for your valuable suggestion and answers.